# How to offer bounty to a person who answers my question?

Tags: support, bounty

I have a question and i want to offer bounty, how do I do it.
And what exactly is bounty?Is it giving away your reputation to somebody

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all [explained in the help pages](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). [You'll need to have at least 75 reputation to set a bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: ... And another  : )

Comment: just want to know about it as i am a new member

Comment: @ShreeshaEinstien That's OK. The help pages have everything in them, you should ask here only if you can't find it there.